# How can I append multiple div and img tags to a parent div in Vue3.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a total newbie to the vue.js framework.
I'm trying to append multiple child tags to a parent div using vue3.js

Markups are like this:

```html
<div class="partner-slider"> <!--this is parent div-->
  <!--these are children-->
  <!-- <div class="slide">
    <img src="../assets/img/partner/0.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="../assets/img/partner/1.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="../assets/img/partner/2.png" />
  </div> -->
</div>
```

And in vanillaJs, I did this, and it worked well

```js
var mHtml = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 41; i++) {
  mHtml +=
    '<div class="slide"><img src="../assets/img/partner/' + i + '.png"></div>';
}
$(".partner-slider").append(mHtml);
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".partner-slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    //draggable: false,
    //pauseOnHover: true,
    speed: 1000,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 600,
  });
});
```

But in Vue.js environmet, the script above doesn't work and it says the images are not found (404). How can I dynamically append images to the parent div so that I can use the slick slider after all images are loaded?

I was trying to use v-for method and did

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      partners: [
        { url: "../assets/img/partner/0.png" },
        { url: "../assets/img/partner/1.png" },
        { url: "../assets/img/partner/2.png" },
        { url: "../assets/img/partner/3.png" },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

but this looks pretty unefficient considering that I should append 41 images with the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array using your desired length of numbers which will be used to generate the file name in the image path:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      partners: [...Array(10).keys()].map(num => ({
        url: `../assets/img/partner/${num}.png`,
      }))
    };
  },
};
```

Then use `v-for` for rendering it:

```
<div
  v-for="path in data"
  :key="path"
  class="slide"
>
  <img src="path" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you made my day. it worked perfectly after adding url: require(``) method.